# Constructing vector topologies (TVS's)

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Consider the following theorem extracted from *"An Introduction to Functional Analysis"* by Charles Swartz (1992):

> **Theorem 1:** Let $X$ be a vector space. Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a family of subsets of $X$ satisfying:
>
> (i) each $U\in\mathcal{U}$ is balanced and absorbing,
>
> (ii) if
>   $U_1,U_2\in\mathcal{U},\exists U_3\in\mathcal{U}$ such that
>   $U_3\subset U_1\cap U_2$,
>
> (iii) if $U_1\in\mathcal{U}, \exists U_2\in\mathcal{U}$ such that
>   $U_2+U_2\subset U_1$.
>
> Then there exists a unique topology $\tau$ on $X$ such that $(X,\tau)$
>   is a TVS and $\mathcal{U}$ is a neighborhood base at $0$ (not
>   necessarily of open sets) for $\tau$.

I am sure that a few years ago I saw the following theorem in some place but I cannot neither prove it nor find it:

> **Theorem 2:** Let $X$ be a vector space over $K$. Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a family of subsets of $X$ satisfying:
>
> (i) each $U\in\mathcal{U}$ is balanced and absorbing,
>
> (ii) if $U_1,U_2\in\mathcal{U},\exists U_3\in\mathcal{U}$ such that
>   $U_3\subset U_1\cap U_2$,
>
> ($\widehat{iii}$) if $U\in\mathcal{U}$ and $\lambda\in
>  K,\lambda\neq0$, then $\lambda U\in\mathcal{U}$.
>
> Then there exists a
>   unique topology $\tau$ on $X$ such that $(X,\tau)$ is a TVS and
>   $\mathcal{U}$ is a neighborhood base at $0$ (not necessarily of open
>   sets) for $\tau$.

**Question:** How to prove that the sets of axioms $\{(i),(ii),(iii)\}$ and $\{(i),(ii),(\widehat{iii})\}$ are equivalent?
In other words, how to prove the theorem 2?

In the proof of Theorem 1, $(ii)$ is enough to show that the family of all the sets $V$ satisfying $\forall x\in V,\exists U\in\mathcal{U},x+U\subset V$ is a topology. The condition $(iii)$ implies the continuity of the addition and then $(i),(ii)$ and $(iii)$ are used to prove the continuity of the scalar multiplication.

I have tried to do something analogous with $(i),(ii)$ and $(\widehat{iii})$ but without success.

---

**Update:** (i) implies that the maps $\lambda\mapsto\lambda x_0$ and   $(\lambda,x)\mapsto \lambda x$ are continuous at $0\in K$ and at $(0,0)\in K\times X$ respectively.

$(\widehat{iii})$ implies that the map $x\mapsto\lambda_0x$ is continuous at  $0\in X$.
 Then from the equality $$\lambda x-\lambda_0 x_0=(\lambda-\lambda_0)x_0+\lambda_0(x-x_0)+(\lambda-\lambda_0)(x-x_0)$$
we deduce that the scalar multiplication is continuous.

**Question:** How to prove that the addition is continuous?

Comment: Maybe you have to use that $2U  = U + U$ to get addition in the game, so to say?

Comment: I know that $2U\subset U+U$ but I am not sure about the equality.

Comment: Maybe you don't need equality ?

Comment: I doubt that theorem 2 is true. There does not seem a way to prove continuity of addition. @HennoBrandsma: $2U=U+U$ only holds for *convex* sets.